# ERROR: Failed building wheel for prophet, ERROR: Could not build wheels for prophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: macos, pip, python-venv, python-wheel, facebook-prophet

I am trying to install prophet in a venv but I keep getting this error:

```
$ pip3 install prophet 
                                                                                                                                             
Collecting prophet
  Using cached prophet-1.1.2.tar.gz (67 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting cmdstanpy>=1.0.4
  Using cached cmdstanpy-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from prophet) (1.24.2)
Collecting matplotlib>=2.0.0
  Using cached matplotlib-3.7.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (7.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.4 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from prophet) (1.5.3)
Collecting LunarCalendar>=0.0.9
  Using cached LunarCalendar-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting convertdate>=2.1.2
  Using cached convertdate-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting holidays>=0.14.2
  Using cached holidays-0.20-py3-none-any.whl (226 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from prophet) (2.8.2)
Collecting tqdm>=4.36.1
  Using cached tqdm-4.64.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Collecting pymeeus<=1,>=0.3.13
  Using cached PyMeeus-0.5.12-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hijri-converter
  Using cached hijri_converter-2.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting korean-lunar-calendar
  Using cached korean_lunar_calendar-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.0 kB)
Collecting ephem>=3.7.5.3
  Using cached ephem-4.1.4-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->prophet) (2022.7.1)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.7-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (229 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0
  Using cached fonttools-4.38.0-py3-none-any.whl (965 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.4-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (63 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->prophet) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->prophet) (9.4.0)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.3.1
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.0->prophet) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: prophet
  Building wheel for prophet (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for prophet (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [72 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/prophet
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/prophet/stan_model
      01:46:00 - cmdstanpy - WARNING - CmdStan installation failed.
      Version 2.26.1 cannot be downloaded. Connection to GitHub failed. Check firewall settings or ensure this version exists.
      CmdStan installation failed.
      Version 2.26.1 cannot be downloaded. Connection to GitHub failed. Check firewall settings or ensure this version exists.
      Compiling cmdstanpy model
      Installing cmdstan to /private/var/folders/j0/6hfbt3114sxgvtm89dpw84y00000gn/T/pip-install-v5usutic/prophet_ddbf2338b7314134841075e084495eb1/build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/prophet/stan_model/cmdstan-2.26.1
      checking version 2.26.1 availability, retry (1/5)
      checking version 2.26.1 availability, retry (2/5)
      checking version 2.26.1 availability, retry (3/5)
      checking version 2.26.1 availability, retry (4/5)
      checking version 2.26.1 availability, retry (5/5)
      Release 2.26.1 is unavailable from URL https://github.com/stan-dev/cmdstan/releases/download/v2.26.1/cmdstan-2.26.1.tar.gz
      URLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/username/Desktop/projects/test/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/username/Desktop/projects/test/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/username/Desktop/projects/test/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 413, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 398, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 183, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 108, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 325, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/j9/somekey/T/pip-build-env-somekey/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 144, in run
        File "<string>", line 131, in build_models
        File "<string>", line 110, in build_cmdstan_model
        File "<string>", line 94, in install_cmdstan_deps
      RuntimeError: CmdStan failed to install in repackaged directory
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for prophet
Failed to build prophet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for prophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects``
```

I have tried everything to my knowledge and have tried recommendations from people on here with a similar problem and from posts on Github. Can someone help me figure out how to solve this problem so that i can install prophet in a venv.

I am using

- Mac OS 13.2.1
- Python 3.11.2
- PIP 23.0.1

Answer (score 2):

In my case (on MacOS) all I had to do was running the `Install Certificates.command` located into `Applications -> Python3.x`

[image]

After that it worked.